# Exception while sending snmp traps via iReasoning lib

Tags: java, security, snmp

I am using iReasoning lib for sending snmp tarps. It works fine while sending V3 with SHA algorithm, but throws following exception while using SHA224

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA-224 MessageDigest not available
```

I am using Java 7 and iReasoning 6.
Is there any requirements for Java environment or passwords?

```
public void testSendTrap() throws Exception {

    final SendSNMPTrap SNMPTrap = new SendSNMPTrap();

    String host = "127.0.0.1";
    int port = 162;
    String community = "public";
    String oid = "1.3.6.1.4.1.6876.4.5.1.0.200";
    final Varbinds varbinds = new Varbinds();
    varbinds.setOneVarbind(".1.3.6.1.4.1.6876.4.5.1.2.1", new SnmpOctetString("message"));
    String userName = "Armen";

    byte[] engineID = new byte[] { 0x12, 0x45, 0x65, 0x45, 0x56 , 0x28, 0x12, 0x45, 0x65, 0x45, 0x56 , 0x28 };
    SnmpTrapSender.addV3Params(userName, SnmpConst.SHA224, "password", SnmpConst.AES, "password", engineID, host, port);
    long timeTicks = 0;
    SnmpTrap trap = new SnmpTrap(timeTicks, new SnmpOID(oid));
    SnmpTrapSender.sendTrap(host, port, trap, true, community);
}
```

Comment: The SNMPv3 supports HMAC-SHA-1 only out of the box. The exception clearly states that the SHA-224 is not supported

Comment: But according to documentation it supports: 
http://ireasoning.com/snmpapi.shtml
Also corresponding enums exists.

What I am missing here?